# Find smallest value in Array without Math.min

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I find the lowest number in an array without using `Math.min.apply`?

```
var arr = [5,1,9,5,7];
```

```js
const smallest = Math.min(...[5,1,9,5,7]);

console.log({smallest});

//old way
const smallestES5 = Math.min.apply(null, [5,1,9,5,7]);

console.log({smallestES5});
```

Comment: Wow, this question opened up for some of the worst answers/ideas I've seen. At least until MrCode showed up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now when look at my own question.. it looks so silly of me.

Below would be perfect solution to find the smallest number in an array:

`By default, the sort method sorts elements alphabetically. To sort numerically just add a new method which handles numeric sorts`

```js
var arr = [5, 1, 9, 5, 7];

var smallest = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);

alert(smallest[0]);
```

Answer (score 11):

If you must use a `for` loop:

```
var arr = [5,1,9,5,7];
var smallest = arr[0];

for(var i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] < smallest){
        smallest = arr[i];   
    }
}

console.log(smallest);
```

Comment: I don't think it's right to supply a complete answer with working code when the OP didn't demonstrate any attempt to solve the problem himself.

Comment: yeah... be a pro at jquery and jquery ui.. without knowing a simple `for` loop in javascript ..  makes life lot easier..

Comment: @skyline3000 I think that describes about half the answers on SO :). In any case, I wouldn't say this is a complete answer. Maybe if it included some validation of the array or a working demo (as a lot of answers do to this type of question). To be fair I've seen this question a few times but for different languages, it's not the for loop that people seem to have trouble with, rather they don't know how to set the initial value to `smallest`. Hence the other [deleted] answer that was doing `smallest = 1000000000000` before the loop.

Answer (score 2):

just sort the array and take the first value, easy.

if you must use a for loop:

```
var arr = [5,1,9,5,7];
for (var i=0; i<1; i++) {
    arr.sort();
}
return arr[0];
```

Comment: The question says it needs to use a for loop. Also, a code example would be good to include with your answer.

Comment: A loop that executes ONE TIME regardless of other conditions is a waste of code.

Comment: LOL, this is outrageous!!!! Just because the question required a for loop, you added a loop which executes only once, while you kept the underlying concept the same, this is not how it works...This is not how any of this works :D XD

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution using a for loop.

```
var arr = [5,1,9,5,7];
var smallest = arr[0];
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i]<smallest){
        smallest = arr[i];
    }
}
return smallest;
```

Returns 1.

Comment: Why not `var smallest = arr[0];` and get rid of all the undefined mess?

Comment: I didn't see that at the point I was writing this. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution without using for loop (ES6).
JavaScript reduce method is a good choice.

```
var arr = [5,1,9,5,7];
var smallest = arr.reduce((prev,next) => prev>next ? next : prev);
var largest = arr.reduce((prev,next) => prev<next ? next : prev);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
const min = (arr) => {
 return arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)[0];
 };
```

this min() function should make the job done

Comment: This is not wrong way to do that, but it is very inefficient since it sorts the array first. @MrCode's answer funds the minimum in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [5, 1, 9, 5, 7,-1,0,5,11,100,-0.5];

var smallest = arr.sort();

console.log(smallest[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a function so you can reuse it as per your needs. Here I just showed an example of the smallest number finder.

```js
function smallestNumber(number){
    let min = number[0];
    for(let i = 0; i < number.length; i++){
        let element = number[i];
        if( element < min ){
            min = element
        }
    }
    return min;
}


let totalNum = [25,50,75,56,11,50,7,9,12];
let result = smallestNumber(totalNum);
console.log('The small number is : ',result);
```